# ¿Cómo optimizar este Procedimiento Almacenado?

Tags: stored-procedure, sql-server-2014

Hola gente como puedo optimizar esta parte de un stored procedure. Ya que revisando el tiempo con el analizador de consultas de sql server 2014, en este codigo es donde se tarda demasiado  mi store procedure, alrededor de 17 segundos para obtener los datos. Habria alguna forma de hacerlo mas rapido?

Estoy usando sql server 2014

```
DECLARE @CONT_PB INT = 1,  @CANTIDAD_PB INT 

        SET @CANTIDAD_PB = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_FS_MOD_ESP_CALIDAD )

                DECLARE @Etiquetas AS TABLE(
                [ID][int] IDENTITY (1,1),
                [orden] [VARCHAR] (MAX),
                [modelo] [VARCHAR] (MAX),
                [etiqueta] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL
            ) 


        INSERT INTO @Etiquetas (Orden, modelo, etiqueta)
        SELECT DISTINCT ksdoco, kslitm, NULL FROM TBL_FS_MOD_ESP_CALIDAD WITH (NOLOCK)


        WHILE @CONT_PB < = @CANTIDAD_PB
        BEGIN

                IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempDB.dbo.#TBL_ETIQUETAS', N'U') IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    DROP TABLE #TBL_ETIQUETAS
                END

             DECLARE @Orden VARCHAR(MAX), @cadena varchar(MAX) = ''
             SET @Orden = (SELECT Orden FROM @Etiquetas WHERE ID = @CONT_PB)

             CREATE TABLE #TBL_ETIQUETAS
            (MODELO VARCHAR(19),  
            ORDEN VARCHAR(30),  
            ETIQUETA VARCHAR(30)
            )  

            INSERT INTO #TBL_ETIQUETAS
            SELECT DISTINCT KSLITM, KSDOCO, ETIQUETA FROM TBL_FS_MOD_ESP_CALIDAD WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE KSDOCO = @Orden  ORDER BY Etiqueta DESC

            SELECT @cadena = rtrim(Etiqueta) + ', ' + @cadena
            FROM #TBL_ETIQUETAS WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE ORDEN = @Orden ORDER BY Etiqueta DESC
               option (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Orden UNKNOWN, @cadena UNKNOWN))----


            IF @cadena != ''
            BEGIN
                SET @cadena = SUBSTRING(@cadena,1, (len(@cadena)-1))
            END

            UPDATE @Etiquetas SET etiqueta = @cadena WHERE Orden = @Orden

            SET @CONT_PB = @CONT_PB + 1


        END
```

Comment: ¿Tu proc. almacenado corre siempre la creación de la tabla? Podrías por favor, incluir la definición de las tablas que usas? Esto pensando en los índices que puedes o no estar usando

Comment: Creo que la función de este procedimiento es el de concatenar las etiquetas en una sola fila por orden. Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Es correcto Luis Cazares.

Comment: Y de cuantos registros estamos hablando? y los indices?

Comment: Son alrededor de 2584 registros. Y no tengo permiso para ver los indices. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás realizando muchos pasos para un problema bastante simple. Hubiera sido mejor que indicaras lo que hace el procedimiento almacenado para dar una solución más simple. Hasta antes de la version 2017 de SQL Server, la opción más común de resolver tu problema de forma sencilla es la siguiente:

```
SELECT KSDOCO AS orden,
    KSLITM AS modelo,
    STUFF(( SELECT ',' + ETIQUETA
            FROM TBL_FS_MOD_ESP_CALIDAD i
            WHERE i.KSDOCO = o.KSDOCO
            --AND i.KSLITM = o.KSLITM /*Me parece que falta esto en el código original*/
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM TBL_FS_MOD_ESP_CALIDAD o
GROUP BY KSDOCO, KSLITM;
```

Trataré de explicarlo un poco. Primero estamos agrupando todo por KSDOCO y KSLITM para evitar datos duplicados. Escogemos esta opción en vez de DISTINCT porque así agrupamos antes de concatenar, ya que DISTINCT primero concatenará y luego elimina los duplicados.

Después creamos una subconsulta relacionada que nos regresa cada etiqueta precedida por una coma. Relacionamos la tabla de la subconsulta con la tabla de la consulta principal con las columnas necesarias. Para concatenar las múltiples filas que regresaría la subconsulta, usamos `FOR XML PATH('')` que las combina en un XML con la ruta principal con una cadena vacía y los elementos sin nombres ya que no le dimos un alias a la columna. La instrucción `,TYPE` indica que lo regrese como un tipo XML y `.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')` convierte los elementos en varchar(max).

Por último, usamos STUFF para quitar la primer coma de cada cadena. STUFF permite remplazar una parte de una cadena con otra cadena y usa 4 parámetros. El primero es la cadena a modificar (las etiquetas concatenadas). El segundo es la posición en la que debe iniciar la segunda cadena (En este caso 1 por ser el inicio). El tercero es la cantidad de caracteres a remplazar (1 porque solo es la coma). El cuarto es la cadena que se insertará (una cadena vacía en este caso). Así que para esta solución, reemplazamos el primer caracter (una coma) con una cadena vacía.

A partir de 2017, puedes usar la función STRING_AGG para hacer la consulta más sencilla.

```
SELECT KSDOCO AS orden,
    KSLITM AS modelo,
    STRING_AGG(ETIQUETA, ',') AS ETIQUETAS
FROM TBL_FS_MOD_ESP_CALIDAD
GROUP BY KSDOCO, KSLITM;
```

Comment: Hola. En que parte pondria eso? La verdad no he usaso el STUFF. Saludos. Y gracias..

Comment: Amplié un poco la explicación de STUFF. Pero puedes revisar más ejemplos en la documentación de Microsoft (seleccionala desde SSMS y presiona F1). El código que compartí, reemplaza por completo el código que publicaste.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya logre implementarlo. De 17 segundos ya ahora se ejecuta en 6 segundos. De antemano, otra vez muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Aún así, me parece mucho tiempo. Pero es complicado dar opciones sin tener más detalles.

Comment: Si de hecho, pero ya con esa guia que me dio puedo seguir optmizando. Saludos!!